# partial differential,stationary point and classify the point

Tags: partial-derivative

I have a question about partial differential , stationary points and to classify those.

$$f(x,y) = e^x + x + \frac{xy^2}{2} - 2xy +6y - \frac {3y²}{2}$$

so the partial diffs are(quite sure it's right):

$$f_y = xy-2x+6-3y = (x-3)(y-2)$$
$$f_x = e^x +1 + \frac{y}{2}(y-4)$$
$$f_{yy} = (x-3)$$
$$f_{xx} = e^x $$

My task was to show that $(0,2)$ is a stationary point and then i should classify the point. I've shown it by setting $f_x,f_y = 0$. What i don't manage to do is classifying the point. Can i get some help with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) in the given point and look for its eigenvalus (or at least its sign).

If you have a 2x2 matrix $H$ (as in your case) it is very easy to find the sign of the eigenvalues since:
$$
\det H = \lambda_1 \lambda_2\\
\mathrm{tr} H = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2
$$
so if $\det H < 0$ then you have a *saddle point*, otherwise you have to check the trace: if it is positive you have a *local minimum* if it is negative you have a *local maximum*.

Comment: There are no other way? can't remember we have been through that method in class. But i cant remember any other way either so..